# How do I configure endpoint and certificates for Cassandra in the storage_config block?

Tags: cassandra, grafana, grafana-loki

I'm trying to setup a custom cassandra storage in storage_config cassandra block.
I was referring to this docs https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/examples/#6-cassandra-snippetyaml

In this they've mentioned usage for username and password but i want to configure it using endpoint. Does this cassandra block in storage_config allows using endpoint & certs ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that way, yes.  In their documentation, it looks like they use the `addresses` term instead of "endpoints."  Also found info on SSL in this [doc](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/). Do a find for "Use SSL when connecting to cassandra instances" and this is underneath:

```
# Use SSL when connecting to cassandra instances.
# CLI flag: -cassandra.ssl
[SSL: <boolean> | default = false]
```

## Require SSL certificate validation.

```
# CLI flag: -cassandra.host-verification
[host_verification: <boolean> | default = true]

# Policy for selecting Cassandra host. Supported values are: round-robin,
# token-aware.
# CLI flag: -cassandra.host-selection-policy
[host_selection_policy: <string> | default = "round-robin"]

# Path to certificate file to verify the peer.
# CLI flag: -cassandra.ca-path
[CA_path: <string> | default = ""]

# Path to certificate file used by TLS.
# CLI flag: -cassandra.tls-cert-path
[tls_cert_path: <string> | default = ""]

# Path to private key file used by TLS.
# CLI flag: -cassandra.tls-key-path
[tls_key_path: <string> | default = ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the docs in the link you provided, you'll see that you need to configure the SSL parameters in the same Cassandra block.

Here's an example of what it would look like:

```
storage_config:
  cassandra:
    ...
    SSL: true
    CA_path: /path/to/ca
    tls_cert_path: /path/to/tls_certificate
    tls_key_path: /path/to/tls_key
    ...
```

Of course, you'll need to configure other parameters such as authentication credentials and contact points (`addresses`).

For details, see [Grafana Loki `storage_config` parameters](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/#storage_config). Cheers!